# Поиск спец-символов Unicode в регулярных выражениях

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var str = "«Lorem» ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.";

alert( str.match(/«\S»/) );
alert( str.match(/\u00AB\S\u00BB/) );
```

Как в данной строке найти слово заключенное между вот такими кавычками «»? В данном случае, нужно найти слово Lorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.match(/«\S+»/)` прекрасно работает и выдаёт корректный результат. Вы забыли `+`.

Comment: А что будет, если текст такой: `«lorem ipsum»` ?

Comment: @ReinRaus Тогда надо `/«.+»/` или `/«.+?»/`, вестимо. Думаю, с этой частью автор справится. :)

Answer (score 0):

Не буду рассматривать случай вложенных кавычек. Например такой:

```
«ООО «Рога и копыта»»
```

Для одинарных кавычек корректным будет такое регулярное выражение:

```
/«[\s\S]*?»/
```

Comment: `\s\S` можно заменить на `.`. :)

Comment: @Discord наличие тэга [tag:javascript] должно подсказывать, что нельзя :)

Comment: Ох, JS...​​​​​​

Comment: @Discord здесь написал http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21649258#21649258

Comment: извращаться так по полной :) `/«[^«»]+»/g` будет принимать переводы строк и заодно не принимать поломанные/вложенные сегменты